# React native paper drop down issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, drop-down-menu

This code is working fine in the emulator but on the web, the dropdown is not closing. Can you please help why it is not closing on the web browser?

react-native-paper

npm i react-native-paper-dropdown
https://fateh999.github.io/react-native-paper-dropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwMOw.png)

```
const [showDropDown, setShowDropDown] = useState(false);
const [SelectDivision, setSelectDivision] = useState('');
const [showMultiSelectDropDown, setShowMultiSelectDropDown] = useState(false);
const SelectDivisionList = [
    {
      label: 'South',
      value: 'South',
    },
    {
      label: 'North',
      value: 'North',
    },
    {
      label: 'East',
      value: 'East',
    },
    {
      label: 'West',
      value: 'West',
    },
  ];
const AppDropDown = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.DropDownDesign}>
        <View style={{width: '25%'}}>
          <DropDown
            label={'Select Division'}
            mode={'outlined'}
            dropDownStyle={{
              borderColor: '#322b7c',
              borderWidth: 0.7,
              borderRadius: 4,
              borderStyle: 'solid',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
            }}
            visible={showDropDown}
            showDropDown={() => setShowDropDown(true)}
            onDismiss={() => setShowDropDown(false)}
            value={SelectDivision}
            multiSelect
            setValue={setSelectDivision}
            list={SelectDivisionList}
            inputProps={{
              right: <TextInput.Icon name={'chevron-down'} size={15} />,
            }}
            /*  inputProps={{
                right: <TextInput.Icon name={'caret-down'} size={15} />,
              }} */
          />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't Reproduce your error due to the code missing the imports, this issue can be fixed by adding the `onBlur` prop to the DropDown component that sets `visible` to false when losing focus. try this out:

```
 <DropDown
  label={'Select Division'}
  mode={'outlined'}
  dropDownStyle={{
    borderColor: '#322b7c',
    borderWidth: 0.7,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }}
  visible={showDropDown}
  showDropDown={() => setShowDropDown(true)}
  onDismiss={() => setShowDropDown(false)}
  onBlur={() => setShowDropDown(false)} // Add this line
  value={SelectDivision}
  multiSelect
  setValue={setSelectDivision}
  list={SelectDivisionList}
  inputProps={{
    right: <TextInput.Icon name={'chevron-down'} size={15} />,
  }}
/>
```